# MySQL Query Works with Tables, Doesn't work with View (Merge), Does work with View (TempTable)

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a legacy MySQL database that was migrated from an Access database. It's awful, but I can't change that part. I don't know where the problem is, but I've done a lot of debugging and experimenting to find where the problem may be. Hopefully you can help me find the issue.

I cannot provide the specific table or view definitions due to legal privacy reasons.

The db has tables A, B, C.... and views M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T. The views are building upon one another, so T is selecting from R+S... R+S are selecting from O+P+Q.

At a certain point, the results of the views break down and start returning incorrect results even though the inputs are correct.

In Access, view R has 50k rows. In MySQL, view R has 50k rows. (and data matches)

In Access, view S has 35k rows. In MySQL, view S has 35k rows. (and data matches)

In Access, view T (which joins R+S) has 24k rows.

In MySQL, view T has 51k rows, but should have 24k. That's the problem.

As an experiment, I created real tables that mirror View R and View S (i.e. tableR has the same column definitions as viewR), then selected viewR -> tableR and viewS->tableS. Then I ran T's query against those ***tables*** instead of the ***views*** and it worked perfectly. I got the 24k rows.

I tried changing the `ALGORITHM` in the create view definition for R and S. It was previously set to `ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED`. I changed it to `ALGORITHM=TEMPTABLE` and then ran T's query. The query was SLOOOOOOW (like 5 minutes) but it eventually gave me back the correct 24k rows.

So, there is my problem. When the view is using `ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED` (I assume that means it is using `ALGORITHM=MERGE`) then the query is fast but wrong. When it's using `ALGORITHM=TEMPTABLE` its unworkably slow but correct.

What could cause a View to return incorrect results like this?

The views aren't complicated, they usually just contain a select statement with a single join and maybe a where clause. They were broken up like this originally to help the developer grasp each of the steps in small, bite-sized chunks.

Comment: That sounds like an optimizer bug in MySQL, assuming the "view" in Access isn't just Access querying the MySQL view, but rather Access doing its own joining.  If Access is just querying the MySQL view then the report doesn't makes sense at all.  The general query log in MySQL will confirm what Access is doing, but I'd be interested in the output of `SELECT @@VERSION;`.  `TEMPTABLE` and `MERGE` (the default wherever it's allowed) should always produce the same result.

Comment: Also, do you get any sense of the nature of the error, with the 51K rows?  What does the query, inside view T do, if you just run it against the other views (not as a view, but just as a query)?

Comment: The Access db and the MySQL db aren't interacting with each other. I'm just running the Access vs MySQL queries side-by-side to check for errors. MySQL is only interacting with MySQL.

Comment: When I'm running the T query to get the 51k rows, I'm not actually selecting from the T view, I'm just directly performing the SQL that T would have done on my behalf. I haven't been able to get a sense of what's wrong from the data because the dataset is just so large. I've tried counting and grouping, but no clear indicator shows through.

Comment: Ah, okay, I thought you were using Access as a front-end for MySQL.  So the T view as `TEMPTABLE` returns the correct 24k-row result, but SELECT directly from T (not the equivalent query) still returns 51k? Does `SHOW WARNINGS;` return anything after any test query?  What if you declare T view explicitly as `ALGORITHM=MERGE`?  Is there anything in the joins whose result might vary if there were a collation issue? e.g. If server thinks string 'A' = string 'a', returns 51k rows but if 'A' != 'a' returns 24k?  `SELECT @@VERSION;` on MySQL please so we can check for known optimizer issues.

Comment: I'll try explicitly setting the algorithm=merge on Monday as well as the Version. Thank you for your help!

The two tables being joined are being joined on integer fields. They are primary keys in other tables. View T is just kind of a map between two people and objects.

Comment: I tried using the algorithm=merge, but it didn't change the results. In the end, I convinced the client to abandon the old views and let us rewrite the queries. We managed to get the query speed from 8 seconds to 0.125 seconds.